# Create multiple files with different extensions with one command

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash

I am looking for a way to create multiple files with one command and automate the process.
They should share a common name but different extensions. The extensions are always the same.
For example index.js, index.css, index.html
So instead of using

```
touch index.js, index.css, index.html
```

I would like to have an miracoules command which does something like this:

```
*miracle* index
```

and 3 files are created.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like

```
touch index.{js,css,html}
```

should work. Which of course can then be turned into a shell function with

```
miracle() {
    [[ "$1" ]] && touch -- "$1."{js,css,html}
}
```

<sub>The test ensures that the files only get created if a name is passed as an argument, the `touch --` ensures that `miracle -foo` doesn't lead to an error.</sub>

and used as

```
miracle index
```

To have this defined automatically in `bash` add the function definition to `~/.bash_profile`, for `zsh` use `~/.zprofile`.